# "No suggestion is returning after spellchecking in solr"

Tags: xml, solr, spell-checking

I have been trying to implement **Solr** on my **Localhost** and using the given examples in it for testing the functionality and want to test the spellcheck functionality.

So I tried reading the official documentation and some articles on how to do so and tried implementing it but after sending the query no suggestions are being returned.

Here is my **solrconfig.xml**

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">fieldspellcheck_en</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Here is the stuff I've edited in **managed-schema** (previously known as **schema.xml**)

```
  <fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <field name="fieldspellcheck_en" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<copyField source="*_txt_en" dest="fieldspellcheck_en" />
```

So I sent a query

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/films/spell?spellcheck.q=blak&spellcheck=on
```

The Response I was expecting includes suggestions including `black, blue etc..` but the response I got was

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "spellcheck":{
    "suggestions":[],
    "correctlySpelled":false,
    "collations":[]}}
```

No suggestions were returned.

Why am I not getting any suggestions? What are the changes I should do

Comment: Do you have any content in the `fieldspellcheck_en` field? What does the field return if you query for the document you expect to get back with the suggestion?

Comment: I am copying the text from dynamic field to ```fieldspellcheck_en```-                                                                      ```<copyField source="*_txt_en" dest="fieldspellcheck_en" />```

Comment: Also whenever I'm reloading after doing these changes and visiting solr admin panel I'm getting an error:
```org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: class java.lang.Float cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Float and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')```

Comment: But is there any content returned for those fields? That error also seems rather relevant - what's the complete stacktrace?